# Solhint "Explicitly mark all external contracts as trusted" - how to fix

Tags: solidity, contract-development, security

From my smart contract I am emitting an event defined in the interface (that my contract inherits/implements). I keep getting solhint warning about "Explicitly mark all external contracts as trusted or untrusted". Can someone help describe what this warning is about and how to go about fixing it?

```
contract MyContract is IERC1155 {
  // some code here
  
  function _safeTransformFrom(/* params here */) internal virtual {
    // code here
    emit TransferSingle(/* params here */) -- THIS LINE throws warning 
}
```

Comment: Can you share all your smart contract code?